# how to disable jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using pipeline jobs with Jenkins 2.0, but I don't see option 'disable job' as I was used to in older Jenkins versions. Am I missing something? Is it still possible to disable (pipeline) job?

Comment: As far as I know based on looking through the source code, there is no disable function support. But hopefully get confirmed from some other people.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can simply use the "Disable Project" option from Jenkins 2.89.4 onward in order to disable the pipeline Jobs.

Answer (score 27):

- go to job configuration
- under "Build Triggers" select the "Disable this project"
- save

[image]

Comment: There is no "Save" in multi branch pipeline

Comment: @David I believe this is if your jobs are built automatically by a separate job finder - ours is called "seeder" but that may be an internal name.

Answer (score 23):

If you don't find the disable button. This should do the trick for most of the Jobs. Just append `/disable` to the end of Job URL. Then Jenkins will redirect you to a page where you can `Post`. Same applies for `/enable` too

[image]

Comment: Note that any config change toggles the flag, so you have to keep disabling it with this workaround.

Comment: I found out that I'm missing the needed permission this way. 
Weird that Jenkins just hides the "enable/disable" button in that case...

Comment: FYI - no indicator of disabled status on the job.  Though you can tell if you make note that the job's icon changes from the pipeline symbol to a dim folder.

Comment: This can fail with the error `[user] is missing the Job/Configure permission` and no obvious way to provision that privilege.

Answer (score 18):

There is no option to disable jenkins-pipeline job.

The following jira ticket is tracking the issue:

> https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27299

Comment: Disable option was added in Pipeline Job v.2.11 on May 12, 2017

Comment: @ALex_hha but *how* is the option used?

Comment: Even though you can't disable the actual job, what you can do for a multi-branch pipeline is to add a filter for the branch names that excludes all branches (with a wildcard).

Comment: @JoanRieu This immediately and completely wipes out the build history for that job; even if you undo the filter the first build starts back at 1

Comment: Follow-up to my previous comment: you can prevent this by marking at least one build in each branch "keep forever". This causes the branch to be disabled instead of removed

Answer (score 15):

For multibranch pipeline projects,

- Click on pipeline 'configuration'
- Under the 'Branch Sources', below 'Property Strategy'

  - click on 'ADD PROPERTY'
  - select "Suppress automatic SCM triggering"

Now, no github branch trigger will run a build job. (This will disable triggers for all branches)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case and found that a lot of our jobs are/were set up by an automatic "seeder" job that created them from Job DSL, and their configurations aren't editable. So i went to GitHub and disabled the webhook connecting the two. So the job is still active, but should never be triggered by GitHub activity anymore.

Comment: I just had to try this again and it didn't stop the hooks and the builds, so this may not work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, your Jenkins jobs are automatically created by a DSL workflow, you won't be able to edit the configuration of the top-level Job, that contains all the actual branches, to disable the automatic builds from github hooks. I can't currently find a way to programmatically disable an entire pipeline in the jenkinsfile, outside of using the `when triggered by` clause on every stage as [mentioned in this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55121241/556078). Besides, that would cause it to run and succeed, which might not be what we want.

So the solution that felt least-hacky to me was:

1. Change the name of the Jenkinsfiles on all branches in your repo to something other than `Jenkinsfile`, so that Jenkins' SCM polling doesn't pick it up. I chose `Jenkinsfile.manual`. This assumes that the job-auto-creator is set to look for "Jenkinsfile"; adjust as necessary.
2. The auto-created job should delete itself the next time it scans the repo, whether that's from the github hook, a scheduled scan, or you pressing "scan now".
3. Manually create a new Multibranch Pipeline job for your repo, setting the **Build Configuration** to look for `Jenkinsfile.manual` (or whatever you choose to call it).
4. Configure whatever branch Behaviors you would normally use, but also add a Property Strategy of **All branches get the same properties > Suppress automatic SCM  triggering**.

This feels "right" to me, your mileage my vary.

Answer (score 0):

I excluded all branches (`Exclude: *`) in my `Branch Sources` -> `GitHub` -> `Behaviors` -> `Filter by name (with wildcards)` -> `Exclude` section

[image: Jenkins screenshot: Branch Sources -> GitHub -> Behaviors -> Filter by name (with wildcards) -> Exclude: *]